# Max Age of a EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have been using AWS EC2 as "normal" VPS hosting provider for the past 3 months - simply because it is well integrated to other AWS services as well as the price doesn't make a big difference using reserved instances for me.

Is there a maximum age at what an EC2 instance should be replaced, or are they able to run "forever"? I'm not talking about retirement.

Thanks for your help/insights!

Comment: You can run them indefinitely. There are scenarios where the underlying host may crash or need replacement (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-retirement.html) and scenarios where your EBS volume might be blown away, so you'd still want a disaster recovery and backup plan. You'd also want to keep the software on that instance updated.

Comment: thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no time limit to the life of an EC2 instance.

Of course, good hygiene still applies. Run updates. Make sure your credit card on file is current. Take backups. And so on.

Comment: thanks for your comment!